# identical sets == False anyone know why?

Tags: python, set

I created a code that compares between sets, when I intersect between two sets, I want to check if they are the same. However the last line of code that does the check returns false, does anyone know why?

```
x = ['bomb', 'lock', 'clock']
y = ['bomb', 'lock', 'clock']
def cards_intersect(card1, card2):
    card1 = set(card1) #turning cards into sets
    card2 = set(card2)
    return card1.intersection(card2) # return intersection of sets
print(x)
print(cards_intersect(x, y))
print(cards_intersect(x, y) == x) #why false?
```

Comment: `x` is a list and `cards_intersect(x, y)` is a set, `['bomb', 'lock', 'clock'] != set(['bomb', 'lock', 'clock'])`. `card1 = set(card1)` is only changing anything *inside* the function.

Comment: set is unordered, so even if you convert set to list and compare, it can give False, `print(list(cards_intersect(x, y)) == x)` is also `False`

Comment: Did any of the answers help you out? if so, consider marking one of them as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from your `print` statements

```
['bomb', 'lock', 'clock']
{'bomb', 'lock', 'clock'}
```

`x` and `cards_intersect(x, y)` are different. The first one is a list, the second one is a set. You may want to compare two sets:

```
print(set(x) == cards_intersect(x,y)) # True
```

Answer (score 1):

`cards_intersect(x, y)` and x has different type.

`type(cards_intersect(x, y))` is `set`, `type(x)` is `list`.

It is like the difference between `1` and `'1'`

Answer (score 0):

The `cards_intersect` function only changes card1, card2 inside the function's scope. Therefore when you are comparing `cards_intersect(x, y)` which returns a **set**, to the **list** `x` - you get `false`.
You can compare in the following way:

```
print(cards_intersect(x, y) == set(x))
```